# How nested function access variables in Javascript at a later time without declaration?

Tags: javascript

In below code how the parameters passed to 'DPerson' function survive even after call to this function has ended successfully. If this is related to how stack and heaps work, can anyone explain it in more detail with respect to this example.

I was of the understanding that, a 'var name = "someValue"' property need to be created in at least one of the execution contexts to print something in console log. But apparently my understanding is wrong.

```js
function DPerson(name, age, job) {
  var o = new Object();

  o.sayName = function() {
    console.log(name);
  }

  return o;
}

var dperson1 = new DPerson("Ahu", 55, "Wild life expert");
dperson1.sayName();
```

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called a [closure](https://medium.com/dailyjs/i-never-understood-javascript-closures-9663703368e8) :)

Comment: In this particular code only `name` will "survive" - not `age` or `job`. And the reason it does survive is because the `sayName` method of the returned object has a "closure" over the `name` variable. There are probably thousands of good explanations online of how closure works in Javascript, I suggest you read some if you're confused by this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing here is a `closure`. When you define a function inside another function, the child function has access to the lexical environment of the parent and keeps that even after the parent has returned. `name` is defined in the parent when you create the parameters to `DPerson`. The child function, `o.sayName` has access to this and retains access to it after the parent returns.

See [MDN - closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more

Answer (score -1):

Yes variables in javascript survive even after the function ended. A function is in short a scope in javascript.